# Extract string of numbers from URL using regex PIG

Tags: regex, apache-pig, extract, regex-lookarounds

I'm using PIG to generate a list of URLs that have been recently visited. In each of the URLs, there is a string of numbers that represents the product page visited. I'm trying to use a `regex_extract_all()` function to extract just the string of numbers, which vary in length from 6-8.  The string of digits can be found directly after `jobs2/view/` and usually ends with `+&cd` but sometimes they may end with `)`.

Here are a few example URLs:

(http://a.com/search?q=cache:QD7vZRHkPQoJ:ca.xyz.com/jobs2/view/17069404+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca)
(http://a.com/search?q=cache:G9323j2oNbAJ:ca.xyz.com/jobs2/view/5977065+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca)
(http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11qAJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clnk&gl=hk)
(http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11AJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clnk&gl=hk)
(http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11qAJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=cl k&gl=hk)

Here is the current regex I am using:

```
J = FOREACH jpage GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(TEXTCOLUMN, '\/view\/(\d+)\+\&')) as (output:chararray)
```

I have also tried other forms such as:

`'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`, `'view.([0-9]+)'`, `'view\/([\d]+)\+'`,

`'[0-9][0-9][0-9]+'`, and
`'[0-9][0-9][0-9]*'`; none of which work.

Can anybody assist here or have another way of going about it?

Much appreciated,
MM

Answer (score 1):

Reason for"Unexpected character 'D'" is, you need to put double backslash instead of single backslash. eg just replace [\d+] to [\\d+]

Here your solution, please validate all your inputs strings

```
input.txt
http://a.com/search?q=cache:QD7vZRHkPQoJ:ca.xyz.com/jobs2/view/17069404+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca  
http://a.com/search?q=cache:G9323j2oNbAJ:ca.xyz.com/jobs2/view/5977065+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca  
http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11qAJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clnk&gl=hk  
http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11AJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clnk&gl=hk  
http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11qAJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928+&cd=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clk&gl=hk  
http://a.com/search?q=cache:aNspmG11qAJ:hk.xyz.com/jobs2/view/16988928)=2&hl=zh-TW&ct=clk&gl=hk  
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://my.linkedin.com/jobs2/view/9919248

Updated Pigscript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' as line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'.*/view/(\\d+)([+|&|cd|)?]+)?',1);
dump B;
```

---

(17069404)
(5977065)
(16988928)
(16988928)
(16988928)
(16988928)

Comment: Added + symbol in the character class to match the sequence of characters.

Comment: Looks good, but does not capture the cases where the string of numbers ends with ")" and not the usual "+&...".

Comment: can you give example of the string?

Comment: Can you tell me which input string its not working?. Are you referring the 6th string in the above input.txt file?

Comment: (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://my.linkedin.com/jobs2/view/9919248) and yes that one (6th) as well

Comment: Updated the script in main page. both 6th and the link you mentioned are working. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PIG, but this regex will match your target:

```
(?<=/jobs2/view/)\d+
```

By using a (non-consuming) look behind, the *entire* match (not just a *group* of the match) is your number.

Comment: ERROR 1200: <line 17, column 68>  Unexpected character 'D'